# Access to WebView from another function in MainActivity class

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-webview, listener

How correctly get access to "view" variable in `onCreate` function ? I want `loadUrl()` but it throws an error on line with, `public Emitter.Listener onServerReceive = new Emitter.Listener() {` on `view = loadUrl`:

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.myapp.MainActivity$7$1.run(MainActivity.java:399)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

```
import com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter;
....

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView view;
    Socket mSocket;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ...
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/loading.html");

    }

    ...

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void websocket_start(){
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://some web com:8888");
            mSocket.on("connect", onConnect);
            mSocket.on("server_receive", onServerReceive);
            mSocket.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
    }


public Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonRootObject = new JSONObject("{ pn: " + global_login + ", pp: " + global_pass + " }");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                mSocket.emit("Auth", jsonRootObject);
            }
        });
    }
};

    public Emitter.Listener onServerReceive = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final String argsStr = TextUtils.join(",", args);
PROBLEM HERE "view" is null ->         view.loadUrl("javascript:receive('" + argsStr + "')");
                }
            });
        }
    };

}
```

What do I do wrong, how to fix it ? thanks!

Comment: It seems likely to me that you want to use OnCreateView(), not OnCreate().  The view you're looking for likely hasn't been inflated yet in the OnCreate().

Comment: Do you have any code that assigns `null` to `view`? Also, are you using `onServerReceive` in any other way?

Comment: Could you post your full code?

Comment: i added onConnect, forgot about it.

Comment: Looks like your 'onServerReceive' is called before 'onCreate()'. Can you check for that?

Comment: in reallity it runs only when i click on screen one button, but in code maybe it runs first before onCreate but i dont know how to make it run after onCreate i dont even know how to check who is running first, im php programmer i dont know how java works , very hard for me.

Comment: this is full logcat, no more errors or something, problem is that "view" is undefined in that scope.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally found the answer and the problem

I had this

```
view.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity(), "access_android");
```

and in web js I accessed android with this `"access_android.websocket_emit()"`

and i think because of `"new MainActivity()"` it was creating a new class where "view" wasn't defined. so I replaced `"new MainActivity()"` with `"this"`

```
view.addJavascriptInterface(this, "access_android");
```

now all works fine ! 
thanks good bye

Answer (score 15):

You're trying to use `view` before it has been initialized. You need to wait until after `view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);` has been called in order to initialize `onServerReceive`.

EDIT: Looking at this some more what's more likely happening is that you're using your instance of `onServerRecieve` before `view` is initialized in `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    onServerRecieve = createListener()
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ...
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/loading.html");

}

...

@JavascriptInterface
public void websocket_start(){
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://some web com:8888");
        mSocket.on("connect", onConnect);
        mSocket.on("server_receive", onServerReceive);
        mSocket.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}

private Emitter.Listener createListener() {
    return new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String argsStr = TextUtils.join(",", args);
                view.loadUrl("javascript:receive('" + argsStr + "')");
            }
        });
    }
};
}

public Emitter.Listener onServerReceive;

}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell that I have the same Emitter.Listener for onConnect, and now they conflict and onConnect is never fired. I edited first post.

Comment: Can you post some more code, it's not clear how you're using the `Emitter.Listener`s, however I'm positive that the problem is `call()` is being executed before `view` is initialized.

Comment: there is no more code, it's it, all other functions is not related to "view" object or mSocket object. Can you just show how to use those two Emitter.Listener together ?